# The dev branch removed the install.sh script?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

The dev branch removed the install.sh script.

why?

How will future releases be deployed and what are the plans.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

File `install.sh` still in dev branch, you could take a look at https://github.com/apache/dolphinscheduler/blob/dev/install.sh